# Images not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following code in a MVC3 program

```
     var images = "\\\\XXXX\\XX\\Files\\" + photo.Thumbnail;
     <a href = "@images" class="grouped-photos" rel="prettyPhoto"> <img src = "@images" alt="@photo.Filename" /> </a>
```

It will only display a image type "PNG". There are two images in each folder. One is the thumbnail the other is the full size picture. If I switch to the full size images

```
      var images = "\\\\XXXX\\XX\\Files\\" + photo.FullImage;
```

then it displays all image types (PNG, BMP,JPG, etc) and the href part will popup the fullsize image". The only difference I can see is

```
      photo.Thumbnail = Thumbnail.ImageXXX.jpg (.bmp, .png, etc)
      photo.FullImage = ImageXXX.jpg (.bmp, .png, etc)
```

I was wondering if the problem is the fat that the Thumbnail image name has a period (.) and the Fullsize image does not. Then too if the Thumbnail image is a .PNG then will display.

Comment: What happens if you type a "jpg" url into the browser's location field? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Note that UNC paths will only work in your domain or intranet (which might be enough for you), not over the public internet.

Comment: None of the systems we are developing are used over the Internet. All are internal systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. From what I was told this will work

```
    var images = Url.Content("\\\\XXXX\\XX\\Files\\" + photo.Thumbnail);
    var fullsize = Url.Content("\\\\XXXX\\XX\\Files\\" + photo.Fullsize);
    <a href = "@images" class="grouped-photos" rel="prettyPhoto"> <img src = "@fullsize" alt="@photo.Filename" width = "90" height = "70"/> </a>
```

Another developer told me to switch to the fullsize image and then set the width and height parameters to reflect the thumbnail size. Now it displays all the images and in the correct size too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Url.Content method to generate the url to the images:

```
var images = Url.Content("~/XXXX/XX/Files/" + photo.Thumbnail);
```

Comment: That works but does not solve the problem. But I had to code it with "\\\\XXXX\\XX\\Files\\" + photo.Thumbnail. Using "~/XXXX/XX/Files/" + photo.Thumbnail does not render the path to the server where the images are stored.